# Be my human compiler: What is wrong with this Python 2.5 code?

Tags: python, django, syntax

My framework is raising a syntax error when I try to execute this code:

```
    from django.template import Template, TemplateSyntaxError
    try:
        Template(value)
    except TemplateSyntaxError as error:
        raise forms.ValidationError(error)
    return value
```

And here's the error:

```
    from template_field import TemplateTextField, TemplateCharField
      File "C:\django\internal\..\internal\cmsplugins\form_designer\template_field.py", line 14
        except TemplateSyntaxError as error:
                                    ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The alternate syntax `except SomeException as err` [is new in 2.6](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3110-exception-handling-changes). You should use `except SomeException, err` in 2.5.

Answer (score 6):

You can't have an empty `try` block like that in Python. If you just want to do nothing in the block (for prototyping code, say), use the `pass` keyword:

```
from django.template import Template, TemplateSyntaxError
try:
    pass
except TemplateSyntaxError as error:
    Template(value)
    raise forms.ValidationError(error)
return value
```

Edit: This answers the original version of the question. I'll leave it up for posterity, but the question has now been edited, and @jleedev has the correct answer to the revised question.

Answer (score 4):

You can't try nothing. If you really have nothing to try, use the `pass` keyword:

```
try:
    pass
except TemplateSyntaxError as error:
    Template(value)
    raise forms.ValidationError(error)
return value
```

But based on my (limited) knowledge of Django, I'd guess you want something like this instead:

```
try:
    return Template(value)
except TemplateSyntaxError as error:
    raise forms.ValidationError(error)
```

Comment: Thanks, you nailed it -- I pasted the wrong code though, which basically matches your correction. Still getting an error though, as I have modified the original question to reflect.

Answer (score 3):

You've got nothing inside your try block.
A try/except block looks like:

```
try:
    do_something()
except SomeException as err:
    handle_exception()
```

Answer (score 1):

In every block in Python you should do something, or if you don't want to do something use the `pass` statement!